# Разработка приложения для android

Tags: android

С чего начать? Что читать?

И еще, я не знаю java. На PHP нельзя писать случаем?

Comment: 20 раз уже было

Comment: на php нельзя, можно на JS, HTML и CSS, но это актуально **только** в случае, когда вы владеете *кунг-фу* JavaScript'ом :D

Судя по формулировке вопроса - забудьте об этом

Comment: JS, HTML и CSS я знаю неплохо. Мне нужно сделать что-то вроде веб-приложения. Или не что-то вроде.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нельзя. Начинать c основ Java.

Comment: или JavaScript ;D

Comment: А перед этим что?

Comment: Никто не мешает на php сделать сайт, а через андроидовский браузер ходить на него... Но это не совсем приложения, но зато на php:)

Comment: Мобильная версия на PHP есть.

Comment: @KoVadim - если точнее - это совсем не приложение

Answer (score 1):

Есть PhoneGap. Можно писать на `html+js+css`